# Unique join table reference inside model scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have 2 models with a `has_many` association:

```
class Log < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :log_details
end
```

and

```
class LogDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :log
end
```

The `Log` table has an `action_type` string column. The `LogDetail` table has 2 columns: `key` and `value`, both string, and a reference back to the `Log` table with a `log_id`.

I want to write 3 scopes on the `Log` model to query for some details joining the `Log` table with `LogModel` twice. Here's a sample:

```
has_many :payment_gateways, -> {where(key: 'payment_gateway')}, class_name: 'LogDetail', foreign_key: :log_id
has_many :coupon_codes, -> {where(key: 'coupon_code')}, class_name: 'LogDetail', foreign_key: :log_id

scope :initiate_payment, -> {where(action_type: 'INITIATE PAYMENT')}
scope :payment_gateway, -> (pg) {joins(:payment_gateways).where(log_details: {value: pg}) unless pg.blank?}
scope :coupon_code, -> (cc) {joins(:coupon_codes).where(log_details: {value: cc}) unless cc.blank?}
```

Using the above scopes, if I try to query for

```
Log.initiate_payment.payment_gateway('sample_pg').coupon_code('sample_cc')
```

I get the SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    `logs`.*
FROM
    `logs`
        INNER JOIN
    `log_details` ON `log_details`.`log_id` = `logs`.`id`
        AND `log_details`.`key` = 'payment_gateway'
        INNER JOIN
    `log_details` `coupon_codes_logs` ON `coupon_codes_logs`.`log_id` = `logs`.`id`
        AND `coupon_codes_logs`.`key` = 'coupon_code'
WHERE
    `logs`.`action_type` = 'INITIATE PAYMENT'
        AND `log_details`.`value` = 'sample_pg'
        AND `log_details`.`value` = 'sample_cc'
```

instead of: (notice the difference in the last AND condition)

```
SELECT 
    `logs`.*
FROM
    `logs`
        INNER JOIN
    `log_details` ON `log_details`.`log_id` = `logs`.`id`
        AND `log_details`.`key` = 'payment_gateway'
        INNER JOIN
    `log_details` `coupon_codes_logs` ON `coupon_codes_logs`.`log_id` = `logs`.`id`
        AND `coupon_codes_logs`.`key` = 'coupon_code'
WHERE
    `logs`.`action_type` = 'INITIATE PAYMENT'
        AND `log_details`.`value` = 'sample_pg'
        AND `coupon_codes_logs`.`value` = 'sample_cc'
```

The first query, because it doesn't resolve the join table references properly, gives me zero results.

How can I modify my scopes/models in such a way to generate the correct query? I think I need a reference to the join table alias inside the scope's `where` clause, but I'm not sure how to get that reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, ActiveRecord has no built-in way to specify the alias used when joining an association. Using `merge` to try merging the two scopes also fails as the condition is overridden.

3 solutions:

1. Use [**Arel**](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rails-oceania/iHlJPSd-lKM/m3_O3CkzZ04J) to alias a `joins`, but that's a bit hard to read, and you still need to repeat the association definition for `payment_gateways` and `coupon_codes`
2. **Join directly in SQL**:

   `scope :payment_gateway, -> (pg) { joins(<<-SQL
   INNER JOIN log_details payment_gateways
     ON payment_gateways.log_id = logs.id 
     AND payment_gateways.key = 'payment_gateway' 
     AND payment_gateways.value = #{connection.quote(pg)}
   SQL
   ) if pg.present? }`

   But you need to add manually the conditions already defined in the associations
3. Finally, my favorite, a **solution that sticks to ActiveRecord**:

   `scope :payment_gateway, -> (pg) do
     where(id: unscoped.joins(:payment_gateways).where(log_details: {value: pg})) if pg.present?
   end`

   `scope :coupon_code, -> (cc) do
     where(id: unscoped.joins(:coupon_codes).where(log_details: {value: cc})) if cc.present?
   end`

**Gotcha #1:** if you use Rails < 5.2, you might need to use class methods instead of scopes.

**Gotcha #2:** Solution #3 might be less performant than #2, make sure to `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to see the difference.

Comment: Thanks! It's a shame that I can't easily get the alias. I think your 2nd option works best for me. The 1st is quite complex, and the 3rd produces a nested query per scope, which becomes really slow as I chain more conditions (I'm using Rails 4.2 BTW). I can get rid of those associations too, because I defined them to help out specifically in just these scopes anyway, so I don't have to worry about the condition getting repeated.